# Estimate the maximum

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, bayes-theorem, maximum-likelihood

Assume that for $i = 1,2,3,\dots,n$ we have $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, 1)$ and assume that we know many of $\mu_i$s are zero.

How can we estimate the maximum of $\mu_i$s with a sample of $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ such that each $x_i$ is modelled by $X_i$

Can we use maximum likelihood? Or the Bayes rule?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You would require a little bit of information on how the $\,u_i$ are modelled. I.E if they were uniform over an interval. Or themselves normally distributed.